# firebase googleapis not verifying the token for nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, express, authentication

I'm trying to get the user verify by the firebase phone authentication. verifying the phone number in the frontend and then sending the token to the backend for verification but it seems to be not verifying the token.
this is frontend

```
const verify = () => {
    let recaptcha = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha',
      {
        'size': "invisible",
        'callback': function (response){
        },

      }
    );
    firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, recaptcha)
    .then(function (e) {
      let code = prompt('enter the otp');
      if (code == null) return;
      e.confirm(code)
      .then(async (result) => {
        const token = await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true);
        
        fetch("http://localhost:9999/auth", {
              method: 'POST',
              body: JSON.stringify({ phoneNumber: phoneNumber, result }),
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
               // "CSRF-Token": Cookies.get("XSRF-TOKEN"),
               authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                Credentials:"include"
              }
            }).then((r) => r.json())
              .then((resp) => {
                console.log("got data", resp);
              })
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error,"error")
      })
    })
  }
```

and this is the backend

```
 const checkIfAuthenticated = async (req, res, next) => {
    //getting the token with the help of getAuthToken
   getAuthToken(req, res, async () => {
      try {
        const { authToken } = req; //getting the auth token from request.
        console.log("auth token",authtoke);
        const userInfo = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(authToken,true); //verifying the token and user.
         console.log(userInfo);
        req.authId = userInfo.uid;
        console.log(req.authId,"authId");
        return next();

      } 
      catch (e) { //any error come or you are not authorised.
        return res
          .status(401)
          .send({ error: 'You are not sfdauthorized to make this request',e });
      }
    });
  };

 


  //an API hit from client side for verification with the help of middleware 
 app.post('/auth',checkIfAuthenticated,(_, res) => {
    return res.sendStatus(200);
  });  

app.listen(9999);
```

this is the error

```
{error: "You are not authorized to make this request", e: {…}}
e: {code: "app/network-error", message: "Error while making request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND www.googleapis.com. Error code: ENOTFOUND"}
error: "You are not sfdauthorized to make this request"
__proto__: Object
```

the blog I was following is [this](https://dev.to/emeka/securing-your-express-node-js-api-with-firebase-auth-4b5f)